# Is there a way to implement hreflang on subfolder in Shopify

Tags: shopify, hreflang

```
Here my current custom code in shopify. 

<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-au" href="{{ canonical_url | replace: 'us', 'au' }}"  />
```

the output goes like this via source code

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-au" href="/en-au/pages/faqs"  />
```

The problem with the code above is that when visitors view it in other country like UK it won't /en-uk in the URL. I am trying to get to make it more dynamic after /en- so that I can implement on other countries. Here is the code I've tried but it gets error showing "liquid error" in Shopify

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-au" href="{{ canonical_url | replace: '{{ localization.country.iso_code }}', 'au' }}"  />
```

Comment: why you adding the same into code? hardcoded

Comment: it is already done by shopify on shop https://prnt.sc/-ACq7mWPX4wG

Answer (score 0):

If you think that your last part will work, you simply have to extract the second liquid code in a variable and use it.
Here is what I mean:

Instead of

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-au" href="{{ canonical_url | replace: '{{ localization.country.iso_code }}', 'au' }}"  />
```

do like

```
{% assign iso_code = localization.country.iso_code %}
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-au" href="{{ canonical_url | replace: iso_code, 'au' }}"  />
```